# Custom Price for WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How can I have a product in WooCommerce with a base price of $ 20 but the user can buy that product at the desired price, for example the user can buy above the base price or below the base price, thank you for your help, how can I do this? I have the ability.

Comment: WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the "Name your Price" behaviour you need ?
https://woocommerce.com/products/name-your-price/